# Unable to improve transcription accuracy with speech adaptation boost

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-speech-api

I'm using SpeechRecognition Python library to perform Speech to Text operations. I'm using the `recognize_google_cloud` function to use Google Cloud Speech-to-Text API.

Here is my code:

```
import speech_recognition as sr;
import json;

j = '';

with open('key.json', 'r') as f:
    j = f.read().replace('\n', '');

js = json.loads(j);

r = sr.Recognizer();
mic = sr.Microphone();

with candide as source:
    audio = r.record(source);
    print(r.recognize_google_cloud(audio, language='fr-FR', preferred_phrases=['pistoles', 'disait'], credentials_json=j));
```

The function `recognize_google_cloud` send the data captured by the microphone to Google API and selects the most probable transcription of the given speech among a set of alternatives.
The parameter `preferered_phrases`, as explained in this [page of the documentation](https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/docs/speech-adaptation), is used to select an other alternative that contains the listed words.

It is possible to improve these results using [speech adaptation boost](https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/docs/boost). As the version of the SpeechRecognition library doesn't let us to specify a boost value, I updated the `speech_recognition/__init__.py` file with an hard-coded boost value:

```
        if preferred_phrases is not None:
            speech_config["speechContexts"] = {"phrases": preferred_phrases, "boost": 19}
```

Unfortunately, when I execute my code, I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pierre/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/speech_recognition/__init__.py", line 931, in recognize_google_cloud
    response = request.execute()
  File "/home/pierre/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/googleapiclient/_helpers.py", line 134, in positional_wrapper
    return wrapped(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/pierre/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/googleapiclient/http.py", line 915, in execute
    raise HttpError(resp, content, uri=self.uri)
googleapiclient.errors.HttpError: <HttpError 400 when requesting https://speech.googleapis.com/v1/speech:recognize?alt=json returned "Invalid JSON payload received. Unknown name "boost" at 'config.speech_contexts': Cannot find field.". Details: "[{'@type': 'type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.BadRequest', 'fieldViolations': [{'field': 'config.speech_contexts', 'description': 'Invalid JSON payload received. Unknown name "boost" at \'config.speech_contexts\': Cannot find field.'}]}]">

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "spech_reco.py", line 23, in <module>
    print(r.recognize_google_cloud(audio, language='fr-FR', preferred_phrases=['pistoles', 'disait'], credentials_json=j));
  File "/home/pierre/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/speech_recognition/__init__.py", line 933, in recognize_google_cloud
    raise RequestError(e)
speech_recognition.RequestError: <HttpError 400 when requesting https://speech.googleapis.com/v1/speech:recognize?alt=json returned "Invalid JSON payload received. Unknown name "boost" at 'config.speech_contexts': Cannot find field.". Details: "[{'@type': 'type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.BadRequest', 'fieldViolations': [{'field': 'config.speech_contexts', 'description': 'Invalid JSON payload received. Unknown name "boost" at \'config.speech_contexts\': Cannot find field.'}]}]">
```

Is there an error in my request?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understand that you are modifying the `speech_recognition/__init__.py` file of the [SpeechRecognition library](https://github.com/Uberi/speech_recognition) in order to include the "boost" parameter in your request.

When reviewing this file I noticed that it is using the ['v1' version](https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/docs/reference/rest/v1/RecognitionConfig#speechcontext) of the API; however, the "boost" parameter is only supported in the [‘v1p1beta1’ version](https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/docs/reference/rest/v1p1beta1/RecognitionConfig#speechcontext)

Therefore, another of the adaptations that you could make in the code is the following:

`` `speech_service = build ("speech","v1p1beta1", credentials = api_credentials, cache_discovery = False)` ``

With this modification you should no longer see the `BadRequest` error.

At the same time, please consider that this library is a third-party library that uses the Google Speech-to-text API internally. Therefore, if this library does not cover all your current needs, another alternative could create your own implementation directly using the [Speech-to-text API Python Client library](https://googleapis.dev/python/speech/latest/index.html).

Comment: It looks like that [this is the way](https://i.pinimg.com/originals/61/4d/e5/614de537ea516c274f9c95e722fbf9d5.gif). I tried many combinations using Speech recognition and the parameter `preferred_phrases` and audio enhencement, but nothing worked.